# jQuery How can I target the target of 'this'?

Tags: jquery, anchor, this, target

Bear with me while I try my best to explain what I need :)

We have 3 links that are pointing to anchors further down the page, like this:

`<a href="#step1">Step 1</a>` which goes to `<div id="#step1">`

`<a href="#step2">Step 2</a>` which goes to `<div id="#step2">`

`<a href="#step3">Step 3</a>` which goes to `<div id="#step3">`

So what I'm trying to do is dynamically target the element that I'm going to. So if I click on the Step 1 link, I go down to the div with an id of step1, but use jQuery to select the targeted element (the div with an id of step1).

So this snippet doesn't work, but is on the right path I think:

```
$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

...which selects the link that I clicked on - not right! I want to select the element that I'm targeting in that link. Get it? Now, I know I could hard code it, but there HAS to be a way to dynamically target what I want.

If this doesn't make any sense, I'm sorry. I would love any and all help and feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$($(this).attr('href')).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9nub/

PS: note that you don't need to use `#` in the `id` value, so

```
<div id="step1">
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I just couldn't quite figure out how to target what I wanted, but as soon as I saw you're code I knew it was right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's code I use to flash targets of #anchor links. Wikipedia uses similar technique to flash footnotes.

```
/**
 * Temporary highlight targets of #anchor links.
 */
$('a').click(function() {
  if (/#(.*)/.test($(this).attr('href'))) {
    var $target = $('#' + RegExp.$1 + ', *[name="' + RegExp.$1 + '"]');
    var repeats = 15;
    function step() {
      repeats--;
      $target[repeats ? 'toggleClass' : 'removeClass']('target');
      if (repeats) {
        window.setTimeout(step, 50);
      }
    }
    step();
  }
});
```

(You'll have to add a 'target' class to your stylesheet do style it.)

BTW, just to let you know: It's possible, using CSS3 alone, using its :target pseudo-class, to style [target elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target):

```
div:target {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the CSS solution :) we're using jQuery anyways, so I figured I would just pick one and run with it.

Answer (score 1):

In your click event for the a tags, this refers to the a element.  So I'm assuming you'd want to get the href from that a tag, and use your own logic to highlight the div.

```
$($(this).attr('href')).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```